# My project wont build and time is running out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, time-limiting

I joined my first ever game jam 8 days ago, and I've put in over 24 hours worth of work at this point. It closes in under 4 hours, and it won't build! I'm panicking! It keeps giving me the errors:

- The type or namespace ShaderGraph does not exist in the namespace UnityEditor
- The type or namespace SearchService does not exist in the namespace UnityEditor
- Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

I have absolutely no idea what to do and time is running out!

I tried deleting the only script I could think of that may be effecting a ShaderGraph, (the shadowCaster2D or the Light2D) and I still got the same errors. I don't know if it's referring to a player like the thing that runs the game, or player as in my player prefab. Please help I can't lose 8 days worth of progress on a technicality! I'm such a novice at this and this is way above my skill level!

Comment: Well. As you only hinted at the errors and show no code. Your build cannot contain editor code. So any references to editor classes/methods will fail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late to be helpful but it may be that you have some custom editor files in places they shouldn't be. Any files that interact with the unity editor should be in a folder labeled "Editor" so that they will not be compiled into the final build. Additionally, when you get errors you don't understand in the future, copying the error message into your search engine of choice is generally a good way to skim for some quick info as to its causes.